# How to update the value of a struct using Q_PROPERTY and stylesheet?

Tags: c++, qt

In this **example**, I'm writting the "stylesheet" on a `QTextEdit` and applying it to the QMainWindow

```
myStruct.a: 10;
myStruct.b: "hello world";
```

`setStyleSheet(textEdit->toPlainText());`

I tried to follow this question:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/82325/best-way-to-access-a-cpp-structure-in-qml/6

But none of the functions is being called `setA` `getA` `getMyStruct` or `setMyStruct` when the **stylesheet** is applied.

What the proper way to update the values of `MyStruct` using the stylesheet?

```
struct MyStruct
{
    Q_GADGET
    int m_a;
    QString m_b;

    Q_PROPERTY(int a READ getA WRITE setA)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString b MEMBER m_b)

    void setA(int a) 
    { 
      m_a = a; 
    }
    int getA() const
    { 
        return m_a;
    }
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyStruct)



class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(MyStruct myStruct READ getMyStruct WRITE setMyStruct NOTIFY myStructChanged)
public:
    MainWindow() : QMainWindow(nullptr), ui(new Ui::MainWindow())
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);

        QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
        ui->centralWidget->setLayout(layout);

        QTextEdit* textEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
        textEdit->setText(R"(
            myStruct.a: 10;
            myStruct.b: "hello world";
        )");

        QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("update", this);
        connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, [=] 
        { 
            setStyleSheet(textEdit->toPlainText()); 
        });

        layout->addWidget(textEdit);
        layout->addWidget(button);
    }    

    MyStruct myStruct;

    MyStruct getMyStruct() const
    {
        return myStruct;
    }

    void setMyStruct(MyStruct val)
    {
        myStruct = val;
        emit myStructChanged();
    }

    void changeEvent(QEvent* event)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::StyleChange) 
        {   
            qDebug() << "style changed"; 
        }
    }

signals:
    void myStructChanged();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow* ui;
};
```

Comment: You seem to be very confused about something. What the link you shared is about is how to use C++ data in **QML**. Supposedly, instead of a `QMainWindow` (= `QWidgets` realm), you are expected to make that work with a QML file run by e.g. a `QQmlApplicationEngine` (= `QML` realm). It has nothing whatsoever to do with style sheets (that belong to the QWidgets module and is only used to customize how widgets look like).

Comment: @Atmoi understand, about the question, do you know, if it's possible to update a struct from a stylesheet? I have found that there are even classes declared as Q_PROPERTY, and also some qproperties- that you can pass multiple values using a stylesheet.

Comment: Your question in its current form is a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please explain what you are trying to do instead of asking help for your attempted implementation of it (which IMO is doomed from the start). And to answer your question: Like I said, stylesheets are **only** used to customized how widgets look like.

Answer (score 0):

> But none of the functions is being called `setA`, `getA`, `getMyStruct` or `setMyStruct` when the stylesheet is applied.

The closest way I have found from changing values with the stylesheet is "**[Dynamic Properties and Stylesheets](https://wiki.qt.io/Dynamic_Properties_and_Stylesheets)**", mentioned in [this thread "Set dynamic property by stylesheet?"](https://forum.qt.io/topic/53620/solved-set-dynamic-property-by-stylesheet/3)

> ### Dynamic properties
>
> For dynamic changes in the user interface look, the property value
> selector can be used in combination with dynamic properties.
>
> Dynamic
> properties were introduced in Qt 4.2 and allow you to assign property
> values to `QObjects` for properties that do not exist at compile time.
> I.e. if you choose to set the a property called urgent to true for a
> `QObject`, that property will stick even tough the class does not
> contain a `Q_PROPERTY` macro for the property urgent.
>
> Creating a stylesheet selector relying on a dynamic property, e.g. urgent, makes it possible to highlight parts of the user interface in a very dynamic manner.
>
> For instance, adding the following rule to the stylesheet above will given any `QLineEdit` with the urgent property set to true red text on a yellow background.
>
> ```css
> QLineEdit[urgent=true] {
>   color: red;
> }
> ```

But the documentation adds:

> ### Limitations
>
> - Any stylesheet aware widget could be turned red using this generic selector
>   (meaning any non-stylesheet aware element is not impacted)
> - the style will not update itself automatically when the value of a property referenced from the style sheet changes. Instead, you must manually trigger an update of the visual appearance of a widget when a styled property changes.

In short: the dynamic properties and stylesheet approach is for changing styles of widgets, not for storing or manipulating arbitrary data structures.

---

If you need to update a struct's properties from the user input, you might need to use a different approach, such as parsing the text yourself or using a form UI with input fields.

For instance, to parse a text, when pressing a button as in "[Qt C++ connect QPushButton click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23845895/6309)":

```cpp
connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, [=] 
{ 
    QString text = textEdit->toPlainText();

    QRegularExpression re(R"(myStruct\.a: (\d+); myStruct\.b: "(.*)";)");
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = re.match(text);

    if (match.hasMatch()) 
    {
        int a = match.captured(1).toInt();
        QString b = match.captured(2);

        MyStruct ms = getMyStruct();
        ms.setA(a);
        ms.m_b = b;
        setMyStruct(ms);
    }
});
```

Here, when you press the button, the text is parsed using a regular expression. The values for `a` and `b` are extracted and used to update the properties in the `MyStruct` instance.
In other words, you are coding yourself the calls to `setA`, `getA`, `getMyStruct` or `setMyStruct`, in response to a UI event.

Comment: Hi, if i would go with a parser option I would prefer to not use a stylesheet/Q_PROPERTY, I was searching if it was possible to update a struct from the stylesheet. Some qproperties like minimumSize, i have been able to update from the stylesheet even it expecting two values instead of usually just one.

Comment: @William I understand. "I was searching if it was possible to update a struct from the stylesheet": the short answer is "no, it does not seem possible".

Answer (score 0):

No, you would not use a stylesheet to update a structure.